# Cumulative Distribution Function and

Tags: probability-distributions

The demand, $X$, for a firm’s product is a random variable with density $f(x) = 2x$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$. The corresponding cumulative distribution function is $F (x) = x^2$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$. The firm’s profits, $Y$ , as a function of $X$ are $Y = \sqrt X − \frac14$ . What is the probability that the firm realizes a loss?

I see that the derivative of the cdf is the density, but I'm not sure how to apply this information to the profit equation. I'm guessing that I need to set the profit function to zero.

Comment: $P(X<1/16)=F(1/16)=1/256

Answer (score 0):

Well, the probability of loss can be said as $P(Y \leq 0)$, which is $P(\sqrt{X}-1/4 \leq 0)=P(X \leq 1/16)=F(1/16)=1/256.$  Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: How did you get the 1/16? I follow after that part. Thanks! This is very new to me.

Comment: Since $\sqrt{X}\leq 1/4 \implies X \leq 1/16$. I hope this helps.